# Visualforce Email Component

Tags: visualforce-component

I have created a Visualforce Component which I am trying to use on VF Email template. Basically to get the recipient Id and use to query Name and Username as these fields arent available via merge fields on VF templates for some unknown reason.

Component

```
<apex:component controller="customController" access="global">

<apex:attribute name="RecipId" type="String" description="{!Receiving_User.Id}" assignTo="{!recip}"  >

                  <apex:repeat value="{!objlist}" var="usr"                                                                     
                    '{!$Label.Hi}' <apex:outputtext Value="{!usr.Name}"
                    '{!$Label.Your_New_Username}' apex:outputtext value="{!usr.Username}">
                  </apex:repeat>                                           
</apex:component>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class customController 
{

public list <User> objlist {get;set;}

public string recip {get;set;}

Public customController()
{
objlist = [Select Id,Name,Email,Username from User where Id=:recip];  
}
  }
```

on my template I included  c:CustomUserComponent

but none of the component text is rendering on the email, not even the Label text.
Can someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify RecipId on component in Email template?

Comment: tried that, doesnt like using Receiving_User.Id. Even when I hardcode a User Id still nothing renders on the email not even the text of the component so basically its not being pulled onto the email

Comment: Well, there is one trick. Component is rendered BEFORE constructor is executed. So just put your SOQL in setter for **recip** variable, and then it will be populated

Comment: Tried that, still no component text being rendered on email

Comment: Well, is that rendered as at all (component itself regardless content under rendered)? Does your user has an access for customController class? and I am talking in case where RecipId should be specified

Comment: I created a dummy VF page with component just to grant access to community profile which is what recipient has. Still nothing no debug so seems my component isnt being initiated somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56919/discussion-between-slm3573-and-kurunve).

Comment: Could you please share your visualforce email template code

Comment: its a lot of HTMl but I just reference the component as so <c:CustomUserComponent />


{!$Label.Welcome_Portal} {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}



Thanks,